# TOC as Section in memoir

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, memoir

The TOC in the article class is formatted as a section. In memoir it is a chapter by default. I would prefer to have the TOC formatted in such a way that its heading gets formatted with the same font (smaller) and distance (closer) to what follows as a section would.

An example with memoir:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Name of my Article}

\tableofcontents*

\section{A Section}

\lipsum{}

\subsection{A Subsection}

\lipsum{}

\end{document}
```

And a roughly equivalent example using article:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\title{Name of my Article}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\section{A Section}

\lipsum{}

\subsection{A Subsection}

\lipsum{}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\chapter{Name of my Article}` indicvates that you are using this completely wrong. Use `\title{Name of my Article}` along with `\maketitle` and the global option `article` to typeset an article, not a bigger report/book.

Comment: Right. Actually I have a few articles that I'll later "glue together" to form a journal. So far I've resorted to making these articles chapters, but that was only a makeshift solution. The TOC concerned here is a detailed one before an individual article, not the short one mentioning only authors and titles for the whole volume.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can use

```
\renewcommand\printtoctitle[1]{\section*{#1}}
\renewcommand\aftertoctitle{}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\renewcommand\printtoctitle[1]{\section*{#1}}
\renewcommand\aftertoctitle{}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Name of my Article}
\tableofcontents*
\section{A Section}
\lipsum{}
\subsection{A Subsection}
\lipsum{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That does about what I need for the moment, I guess the extra space between TOC heading and TOC contents is due to the TOC being a list internally, leaving some space on top of it.

Comment: Where are `\printtoctitle` and `\aftertoctitle` defined?

Comment: I changed your redefinition of `\aftertoctitle` as follows: `\renewcommand\aftertoctitle{\vspace{-\baselineskip}}`, which pulls up the TOC contents for the line that gets added by the TOC being a list. Actually now I'm not sure I want that, but just for the reference.

Comment: See the documentation of [memoir](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/memoir), chapter "Contents lists", section "The class ToC methods", subsection "Changing the titles".