# Where is \printtoctitle defined?

Tags: macros

I can use `\show\printtoctitle` to get its definition,

```
> \printtoctitle=macro:
#1->\printchaptertitle {#1}.
l.5 \show\printtoctitle
```

but grepping for it through my latex installation I don't find it, also latexdef tells me it's undefined. Why is that and where do I find it?

Comment: @SoundsOfSilence: I assume it to be connected to memoir. I was advised to redefine it in a response to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/235575/toc-as-section-in-memoir).

Comment: @muk.li  you are right.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In `memoir.cls` you can find

```
\newlistof{tableofcontents}{toc}{\contentsname}
```

and, inside the definition of `\newlistof`

```
\newcommand{\newlistof}[3]{%
.....
\@namedef{print#2title}##1{\printchaptertitle{##1}}
.....
```

Here, when `\newlistof{tableofcontents}{toc}{\contentsname}` is issued, `\@namedef{print#2title}##1{\printchaptertitle{##1}}` defines a command called exactly `\printtoctitle` which takes one argument and whose meaning is `\printchaptertitle{#1}`.

In other words, it is almost the same as saying

```
\newcommand{\printtoctitle}[1]{\printchaptertitle{#1}}
```